# How to modify binaries in Cisco AnyConnect installer?

Tags: configure, cisco

I need to modify Cisco AnyyConnect Binaries. I had add for example calc.exe via ASDM.

[image: anyconnect custom binary]

Then I press "Apply" and "Save".
Now, when I download AnyConnect installer from the ASA web portal I got the same installer as was before. No changes. There is no calc.exe.

P.S.
Had use this article - [enter link description here](https://explore.cisco.com/c/cisco-anyconnect-sec)

Answer (score 0):

It download and replace local files after successfully connection (Client to ASA).